# c++03 null pointer versus null object pattern: performance implications

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++03

I have some library code which sometimes needs to be run multithreaded, but more usually single threaded. It's a set of small routines which are called very frequently. Previous experience and profiling indicates that extra delays may be detrimental to performance, so I want to avoid unnecessary overheads.

I can't provide a separate instance of the library for single and multithreaded use, nor can I provide a thread safe wrapper the single threaded version. Both these restrictions are due to the design of the library.

My preferred way of protecting the routines when run multithreaded is to use a scoped mutex. My initial thought was along the lines of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752342/78947).

However most of the time the routines are run single threaded, and I don't like the overhead of the null pointer check. This is run on a very slow ARM9 processor and every cycle counts.

In practice I'll probably go with the null pointer check and profile to see what it costs, but I'm wondering whether there's a better way. For example the null object pattern, or having the library call a callback.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like there is some information lacking here to really give the best answer, but I don't really see any reason to use pointers here at all. Presumably you are calling some library code, let's say it's a function called `void foo(int)`. You can't change this code, and it's not thread safe. But you can change your code, right? Instead of calling your code, call a wrapper around `foo`:

```
template <class M>
void foo_wrapper(M& mutex, int x); { std::lock_guard(mutex); foo(x); }
```

Now, you can simply write a trivial no-op mutex:

```
struct NoMutex {
  void lock() {}
  bool try_lock() { return true; }
  void unlock() {}
};

std::mutex m1;
NoMutex m2;
foo_wrapper(m1, 0);  // thread safe
foo_wrapper(m2, 0);  // thread unsafe
```

Because the types are known to the compiler, the second call to `foo_wrapper` will not have any overhead whatsoever.